# Chemical and stellar evolution in stars

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, fusion, matter, stellar-evolution

I'm having an exam soon where I have to discuss/describe the follow figure:

[image]

It's the first figure I have to explain, and it was on the same slide as the one below, so I'm thinking they are somewhat similar. But I can't seem to figure out what's going on in that figure ? "25 solmasser" is "25 sunmasses" if you were wondering. I'm pretty sure it tells me something about the time and evolution of each burning phase in a large mass star, i.e. hydrogen-burning, helium-burning, carbon-burning, neon-burning, oxygen-burning and silicon-burning. But it makes no sense (The first figure), and it's just on a slide with no text or explanation, so I'm not quite sure how to interpret it.
So I was hoping maybe someone could give me some pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the colloquial term for that type of plot is "spaghetti diagram" because you have a bunch of lines running across it. It's really the [mass fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_fraction_(chemistry)) as a function of interior mass. From [our stellar structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_structure) equations, we have that
$$
\frac{dm}{dr}=4\pi r^2\rho,
$$
which is derived from the mass-continuity equation, so you can relate the radius, $r$ (in solar radius units) to the mass (given in solar masses). This type of Lagrange coordinate is the standard for these plots though.

Basically, the plot shows the *dominant* element(s) as you go deeper into the star. The closer to 1.0 it is, the more you're going to find that element. The sharp peaks/drops arise from [nuclear burning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis)--fortunately for you, those are labeled at the bottom, this is not often the case! Note that towards the right side you see ${}^1{\rm H}$ starting to peak while ${}^4{\rm He}$ starting to fall, this is where hydrogen burning takes place; this also indicates that your plot extends much further than what is shown there (which makes sense, given that your plot extends to a little over 8 solar masses for a 25 solar mass star!).

So, for instance, at around 6 solar masses, you have helium burning (triple-alpha process) that produces carbon-12 while destroying the helium. Carbon burning at about 5 solar masses destroys the carbon while producing neon-20 and magnesium-24. And similarly for the other burning processes. Note again, though, that each burning produces more elements than what is shown here, this is only showing the *dominant* species produced.

There is no time evolution in this diagram. This is simply showing you how much of each element at one *particular* time. The type of plot that shows a time-evolution is called a Kippenhahn diagram ([see this, for instance](http://inspirehep.net/record/789890/plots)). These are a bit more complicated, but really only show the *burning* processes as a function of time, rather than a mass fraction of abundances.

Comment: Spot on. The y-axis will be the mass fraction of the labelled element(s) - note the logarithmic scale. "Fe core" will cover a mixture of iron-peak elements, not just iron. This looks like the inner 8 solar masses of a 25 solar mass star about to go supernova.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. I'm not quite sure about the bottom labels (lg($T$) and lg($\rho$)). What to those numbers represent ?
And I'm not sure I fully understand the y-axis, even though you say it's the mass-fraction. Mass-fraction of what ? It doesn't seem to be the same as in figure 2, or am I mistaken ?

Comment: Once again - thank you very much! Much appreciated and informative.